# Change output object's properties of powershell cmdlet based on input parameter set

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I have created a PowerShell cmdlet
`Get-MyName` It has 2 parameter set

#### Parameter Set 1

`Get-MyName`(No parameter)

Output :-

`First: John`

#### Parameter Set 2

`Get-MyName -Full $true`

Output :-

```
First :John

Last :Gardener
```

I want the cmdlet to return same object for both the parameter set. Only difference is that in First parameter set the property `Last` should not be present.

Is there any way I can do it?

Comment: Wouldn't a `param([switch]$Full)` be sufficient?

Comment: I can change Full to a switch parameter. But my  intention of question is different

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do in your script/function is to return the object
with different properties depending on your switch `-Full`

```
function Get-MyName {
   param(
     [switch]$Full
   )

    $Object = [PSCustomObject]@{First='John';Last='Gardener'}

    if($Full){
        return $Object
    } else {
        return ($Object | Select-Object -Property * -ExcludeProperty Last)
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
PoSh> Get-MyName

First
-----
John

PoSh> Get-MyName -Full

First Last
----- ----
John  Gardener
```